# PHP SQL Query Using Array

Tags: php, sql

To put it this question simple, I use the follwoing command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.shortmessage 
FROM `users` a, `rating` b 
WHERE a.userid IN (333333, 101010) 
    AND b.myuserid IN (333333, 101010) 
    AND b.userid LIKE '000000'
```

It returns:

```
id   other_columns    shortmessage
3    Guy1             message from guy1
9    Guy2             message from guy1
3    Guy1             message from guy2
9    Guy2             message from guy2
```

Note that I can use `GROUP BY id` and it will show 2 rows as expected but the message from table 2 will be wrong on guy2.

What I want:

```
id   other_columns    shortmessage
3    Guy1             message from guy1
9    Guy2             message from guy2
```

Comment: How do you define which `shortmessage` should be shown for a particular *Guy*/`id`?

Answer (score 0):

These items ARE all distinct (look at the different `shortmessage` per `id`):

```
id   other_columns    shortmessage
3    Guy1             message from guy1
9    Guy2             message from guy1
3    Guy1             message from guy2
9    Guy2             message from guy2
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick read up on INNER JOIN from w3s

[w3s link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN `rating` ON users.userid=rating.myuserid WHERE users.userid IN (333333, 101010) AND rating.myuserid IN (333333, 101010) AND rating.userid LIKE '000000'
```